# Compose Incanter chart objects to show multiple charts with one view call

Tags: charts, clojure, incanter

I have something like this:

```
(defn plot-simulation [f]
  (let [x (range 1 1000)
        ye0 (->> (run-simulation 5 0.000000000000000000000001) ;; needs to run all 2000 in paralell
               (take 1000)
               (map f))
        ye01 (->> (run-simulation 5 1/10)
                  (take 1000)
                  (map f))
        ye001 (->> (run-simulation 5 1/100)
                  (take 1000)
                  (map f))
        ]
    ;; How to add another chart in the view?
    (-> (c/xy-plot x ye0
                   :x-label "Steps"
                   :y-label "Somethings"
                   :series-label "e=0"
                   :legend true)
        (c/add-lines x ye01
                     :series-label "e=0.01")
        (c/add-lines x ye001
                     :series-label "e=0.001")
        (i/view))))
```

To show three lines from a simulation. Now instead of plotting three lines in one chart I would like to plot three charts with one line in each using only one call to view. Is this possible using Incanter?